# Error in installing mysql module in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am newbie to nodejs.I was trying to install the mysql module using the below command

```
npm install mysql
```

It display the below error.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install mysql
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mysql"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad networ
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mysql"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

npm ERR! Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log

C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

How to resolve the above error? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have checked your Network settings and you are sure that you do not use any proxy you can try this:

```
npm config delete proxy
```

NPM seems to sometimes set wrong proxy configs although none are actually needed. This command will delete the configured proxy.

Please comment your results if you have done this.

Comment: thanks @alxn,I run the above command.it works for me thanks again.